# ¿Cuáles son los atajos de teclado para comentar el código en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Cuales son los atajos de teclado para comentar el codigo en `Android Studio`, tanto para una linea o varias lineas seleccionadas `//`,

```
//Comentar lineas seleccionadas 1
//Comentar lineas seleccionadas
```

como para un bloque de codigo selecionado `/* */`.

```
/*Comentar lineas seleccionadas
  Comentar lineas seleccionadas
  Comentar lineas seleccionadas*/
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Para GNU/Linux

Comentar linea o lineas seleccionadas (Line Comment) :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Comentar bloque de codigo seleccionado (Block Comment):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shif</kbd> +<kbd>/</kbd>

---

## Para Windows

Comentar linea o lineas seleccionadas (Line Comment) :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Comentar bloque de codigo seleccionado (Block Comment):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shif</kbd> +<kbd>/</kbd>

---

## Para MAC

Usar <kbd>Cmd</kbd> en vez de <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> seguido el resto de teclas.

---

Notas: Para anular los comentarios los mismo atajos, si estan activos se desactivan y si estan desactivado se activan.

info: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html#q=keymap

Usted puede consultar cual esta definido para en su entorno:

`File` >> `Settings` > `KeyMap`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pulsando sobre las `teclas/shortcut` definidas usted puede cambiarlas, removerlas o añadir si no estan definidas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5):

Si quieres usar los `atajos del teclado` para generar comentarios que seran para, generar la documentación de funciones, métodos, classes etc.. te pones en la linea superior y escribes `/**` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> te generará automáticamente el siguiente patrón.

Ejemplo:

Inicio:

```
/** + EnterKey
public void myCar(String name, String color){
//tú código
}
```

Resultado:

```
/**
* @param name
* @param color
*
/
public void myCar(String name, String color)
{
//tú código
}
```

Comment: Creo que ahora con los ajuste en tu respuesta, se amolda mas la tematica de la pregunta, Saludos.