# Formatear estilo de comentarios de documentacion en Intellij Idea usando atajos de teclado

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, javadoc

**Planteamiento**

En primer lugar no encontramos en **JavaDoc**, en Java.

Yo tengo el siguiente texto que quiero insertar como parte del JavDoc:

```
Esto es el commentario de JavaDoc que quiero exponer en la 
pagina de stackverflow y que despues voy a diseñar para que sea 
agregado a mi proyecto personal.
Pero tengo una serie de problemas a la hora de insertalo en Intellij IDEA 
que no me ocurre en Eclipse.
```

#### Ejemplo en Eclipse

A continuación mostrar paso a paso como hago en `Eclipse` hasta obtener el resultado que no obtengo en `Intellij`´:

- **Primer paso.** Comienzo poniendo el comentario
- **Segundo Paso** Pego o escribo el texto correspondiente:

  [image: Primer y segundo paso]
- **Tercer y último paso** Pulso la tecla <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd>  y obtengo lo siguiente :

  [image: Tercer Paso]

**Problema**

En `Intellij` hago lo mismo pero **al llegar al paso tercero no me hace nada**.

**Duda**

¿Que teclas hay que utilizar o añadir para que haga lo mismo en Intellij que en Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De esta respuesta del StackOverflow en Ingles:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813662/eclipse-like-comment-formatting-in-intellij-idea

*Lo que más se acerca es Edit | Join Lines. (Ctrl+Shift+J). Tienes que seleccionar las lineas que quieres juntar primero.
Para cortar comentarios muy largos activa lo siguiente Settings | Code Style | JavaDoc | Wrap at right margin.*

Por otro lado, si estás mas cómodo con los atajos del eclipse, los puedes configurar en el IntelliJ:

[En este link dice como:](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Configure+Keymap)
[image: Como configurar shortcuts eclipse.]

Answer (score 2):

> UPDATE por comentario y actualizacion de la pregunta:

entonces quizas lo que busca es esto:

`/**` + <kbd>EnterKey</kbd>

donde `/**` es lo que escribes en el codigo y luego usas <kbd>EnterKey</kbd>

un ejemplo:

```
/** + enter
public void mi_test(String test_parametro_1, String test_parametro_2){

}
```

---

```
/**
* @param test_parametro_1
* @param test_parametro_2
*
/
public void mi_test(String test_parametro_1, String test_parametro_2){

}
```

**Añadido:** Para el tercer paso pruebe lo siguiente `Reformat code`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> seleccionando, para Mac busque en la guia que deje en esta respuesta, en la seccion Editing -> `Reformat code`.

Es la alternativa para al: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> de Eclipse pero ahora mismo no puedo probarlo sobre Intellij Idea.

*quizas no funcione como espera*

---

Si no le funciona como espera siempre puede usar lo siguiente:

`/**` + <kbd>EnterKey</kbd>.
despues seleccione el texto que quiere introducir, y aplique:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shif</kbd> +<kbd>/</kbd>.
despues mueva o corte y pegar, en el lugar que desee, solo tendria que borrar /* */ que estan de mas, (no es una solucion tan practica) pero es la que le puedo decir ahora mismo, pues no puedo probar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

*si tengo la posibilidad de usarlo vere como trabaja y podre borrar esta parte de no ser necesaria*

---

> ANTIGUO

Quizas pueda tratar lo siguiente (para usar el atajo por defecto):

---

**Comment /uncomment** con *line comment* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

**Comment /uncomment** con *block comment* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

---

## Para GNU/Linux

Comentar linea o lineas seleccionadas (Line Comment) :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Comentar bloque de codigo seleccionado (Block Comment):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shif</kbd> +<kbd>/</kbd>

---

## Para Windows

Comentar linea o lineas seleccionadas (Line Comment) :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Comentar bloque de codigo seleccionado (Block Comment):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shif</kbd> +<kbd>/</kbd>

---

## Para MAC

Usar <kbd>Cmd</kbd> en vez de <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> seguido el resto de teclas.

---

Puede ver otros atajos [aqui](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) para diferentes OS, se muestran para GNU/Linux y Windows y aparte para Mac.

(buscar en el link la accion deseada por ejemplo: `Comment /uncomment with line comment` en la pagina para Mac, para ver como seria)

---

> Si lo que desea es remapear los atajos puede mirar esta [pregunta/respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2677/cu%C3%A1les-son-los-atajos-de-teclado-para-comentar-el-c%C3%B3digo-en-android-studio)

Comment: Muchas gracias.No respondes en la totalidad de mis dudas a causa de una mala exposicion,por parte mía de mi duda.De todas formas has abierto el recuerdo de una duda que me ocurria para comentar un bloque y que acabo de resolver con tus respuestas.Destacar tu aporte del pdf ( https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf ) acerca de los diferentes KeyMaps de Intellij.

Comment: @NicolásAlarcón acabo de añadir un update, ¿es eso a lo que se refiere con su pregunta tras su actualizacion? Saludos

Comment: @NicolásAlarcón si mi update es lo que busca, quizas el titulo podria se algo asi -> ¿Cómo puedo **crear los comentario para la documentacion** en Intellij Idea usando atajos de teclado? Saludos

Comment: No exactamente,subo una nueva version para detallar

Comment: @NicolásAlarcón he puesto un **Añadido:** dentro del ultimo update igual es lo que busca.Saludos